# Как сделать scrollable tab?

Tags: android, tab

У меня есть в фрагменте Tabs и мне нужно как на gif [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это мой код, что нужно добавить?

```
package com.example.admin1.bottomtabexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemOneFragment extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public static ItemOneFragment newInstance() {
        ItemOneFragment fragment = new ItemOneFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_one, container, false);
        tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        return view;
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter =
                new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment1(), "Tab1");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment2(), "Tab2");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment3(), "Tab3");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment4(), "Tab4");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabOne =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tabOne.setText("1");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabTwo =(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tabTwo.setText("2");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabThree =(TextView)view2.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tabThree.setText("3");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

        View view3 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabFour =(TextView)view3.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tabFour.setText("3");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
    }
}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Вроде бы просто надо в разметке для `TabLayout` добавить `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

Comment: Вам нужно сделать не табы а viewPager

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из моего кода, все работает:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Fragment mFrag1;

private Fragment mFrag2;

private TabLayout mTabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupViewPager((SelectSweepViewPager) findViewById(R.id.select_sweep_viewpager));

}


private void setupViewPager(SelectSweepViewPager v){
    v.setAdapter(addFragments());
    addTabs(v);
}

private ViewPageAdapter addFragments(){
    mFrag1 = new Fragment();
    mFrag2 = new Fragment();
    ViewPageAdapter a = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    a.addFragment(mFrag1);
    a.addFragment(mFrag2);
    return a;
}

private void addTabs(final SelectSweepViewPager v){
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(v);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_edit);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_collect);
    /*здесь в зависимости от фрагмента отключаем или включаем свип. Можно
      обойтись без этого*/
    if(mTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()==0)v.setSweep(false);
    else v.setSweep(true);

    v.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      /*здесь в зависимости от фрагмента отключаем или включаем свип. Можно
      обойтись без этого*/
            if(position==0) v.setSweep(false);
            if(position==1) {
                v.setSweep(true);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

а вот разметка:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.example.kittenappscollage.mainTabs.SelectSweepViewPager
    android:id="@+id/select_sweep_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать не табы а viewPager

Например:

```
class PagerAdapter
    extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
private int mNumOfTabs;

PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = 4;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment_1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment_2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment_3();
        case 3:
            return new Fragment_4();

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Fragment_";
        case 1:
            return "Fragment_";
        case 2:
            return "Fragment_";
        case 3:
            return "Fragment_";

    }        return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

и заюзать вот так:

```
PagerAdapterAuto mAdapter = new PagerAdapterAuto(getChildFragmentManager());
        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorViewPager"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить свойство в разметку app:tabMode="scrollable"